# Android audio player library supporting playback speed change

Tags: android, audio

Is there any easy-to-use audio player library for Android which supports playback speed change? I know similar question have already been asked but it's 2014 now and I still haven't found easy solution of this problem.

Comment: Similar questions also get closed by moderators just about as fast as they're asked.  Which is at least once a week by my reckoning. Library recommendation questions are not welcome on StackOverflow. Please take the time to read the FAQ.

Answer (score 0):

[`SoundPool`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/SoundPool.html#setRate%28int,%20float%29) class has a method called `setRate (int streamID, float rate)`.

> Change playback rate. The playback rate allows the application to vary
>   the playback rate (pitch) of the sound. A value of 1.0 means playback
>   at the original frequency. A value of 2.0 means playback twice as
>   fast, and a value of 0.5 means playback at half speed. If the stream
>   does not exist, it will have no effect.

Comment: Yes, but I'd like to use complete audio player with play/pause/seekTo functions. Also I'm not sure if SoundPool is good choice for playing longer audio tracks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Sonic-NDK library.